# Cross Compile source code for ARM based Linux system on Mac issue

Tags: linux, macos

```
port install arm-none-eabi-gcc
port install arm-none-eabi-binutils
```

i downloaded the arm tools on my mac.

```
export CCPREFIX=/opt/local/bin/arm-none-eabi-
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=${CCPREFIX}

however it has alot of errors.
tcpdump.c:180: error: ‘struct tcphdr’ has no member named ‘source’
tcpdump.c:238: error: ‘ETH_P_ARP’ undeclared (first use in this function)
tcpdump.c:238: error: ‘ETH_P_ARP’ undeclared (first use in this function)
tcpdump.c:116: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
tcpdump.c:136: error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘struct icmphdr’ 
tcpdump.c:136: error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘struct iphdr’
```

looks like mac doesn't know those Linux defines, structures,

the same code if make in a linux system then its OK.

the question, is using Mac to cross compile code for ARM based linux system doable?

Comment: Do you have the necessary headers somewhere ? I don't own a Mac, but there shouldn't be any problem cross compiling, just as long as you provide the compiler needed information

Comment: @julumme, why? linux headers are different than mac's. I dont expect them the same.

Comment: If you looks at Linux tcp header definition: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/tcp.h?v=3.10 you can see that you have those fields defined. But in Mac (BSD source) https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/master/sys/netinet/tcp.h the struct definition is different. So this is why I thought maybe you have your `target` (arm) platform headers somewhere, and compile against those..

Comment: so, are you suggesting I move my linux header files to the Mac system? and where would I put them?

Comment: No I usually cross compile against my embedded system work area (="SDK"). I have compiled my kernel and created the rootfs (which is the system the board actually runs), and then when cross-compiling any code for it, I just point compiler to use those headers for compilation. If you don't create your embedded environment, at least it should be downloadable from manufacturer of the board ?

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong toolchain. `arm-none-eabi` is for bare-metal ARM systems — that is, ARM systems without an operating system, like microcontrollers — not Linux systems. These systems don't have network stacks (unless you compile your own), so they don't have headers for TCP/IP data structures.

I don't think MacPorts has an appropriate toolchain for this, but you may be able to build one using [crosstool-ng](http://crosstool-ng.org/). The `arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi` sample included with crosstool is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: Is there such thing as cross .configure?  crossing prepping makefile for target system. alot time m makefile is ready for a package and needs to run .configure to prep it. however, in this case it s not for host but for a target system.